# Bash regular expression execution hangs on long expressions

Tags: regex, performance, bash, validation

I need to validate a 38 field comma seperated string. Fields can be numeric, decimal or empty allowed strings.

Problem is when I construct a regular expression for 38 fields and try to execute, it hangs forever and it hangs.

I use following per field reg exps:

```
INT="[0-9]+"
TIM="[0-9]+"
NUM="[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?"
STR=".*"  # --> (also tried "[^,]*" but no change)
```

I constructed my regexps with above expressions.

**1)** This is working fine: (Output: "matches")

```
[[ "str1,1.1,5,6,7,8,9,str2,str3,str4,str1,1.1,5,6,7,8,9,str2,str3,str4,str1,1.1,5,6,7,8,9,str2,str3,str4,str1,1.1,5,6,7,8,9,str2,str3,str4" =~ ^.*\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,.*\,.*\,.*\,.*\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,.*\,.*\,.*\,.*\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,.*\,.*\,.*\,.*\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,.*\,.*\,.*$ ]] && echo matches
```

**2)** This hangs and execution wont complete !!!:

```
[[ "str1,1.1,5,6,7,8,9,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7,str8,str9,str10,str11,2.0,str12,0.0,5.0,str13,12312545645,45456456478,78979754545,12312545645,45456456478,78979754545,78979754545,4.74,0.1245,4.174,0.4245,6,80,str14,str15" =~ ^.*\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,.*\,.*\,.*\,.*\,.*\,.*\,.*\,.*\,.*\,.*\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,.*\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,.*\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,.*\,.*$ ]] && echo matches
```

I thought `.*` is too generic then tried `[^,]*` but nothing changed.

Please advice how can I solve this without splitting by "," once then compare one by one.

---

## !!! Correction !!!

Above I stated:

> STR=".*"  # --> (also tried "[^,]*" but no change)

This is wrong. Noticed that, I failed to replace all of them. When I replace all `.*` to `[^,]` problem is resolved. See below:

**3)**  This is fixed version and working as expected:

```
[[ "str1,1.1,5,6,7,8,9,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7,str8,str9,str10,str11,2.0,str12,0.0,5.0,str13,12312545645,45456456478,78979754545,12312545645,45456456478,78979754545,78979754545,4.74,0.1245,4.174,0.4245,6,80,1,str15,str16" =~ ^[^,]*\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[^,]*\,[^,]*\,[^,]*\,[^,]*\,[^,]*\,[^,]*\,[^,]*\,[^,]*\,[^,]*\,[^,]*\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[^,]*\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[^,]*\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\,[^,]*\,[^,]*$ ]] && echo matches
```

Watch out for [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html) that I learned from this issue.

Comment: Didn't hang on my system.

Comment: On regex101, replacing all `.*` with `[^,]*` does [removes](https://regex101.com/r/jT2lZ7/1) the [catastrophic backtracking error](https://regex101.com/r/jT2lZ7/2). BUT why use a regex?

Comment: I have a data record file containing thousands of lines with this format. I wrote a script to validate and print out invalid line's line number to detect issue. Please suggest if there is better ways.

Comment: What is the system you are using this regex on?

Comment: I made a mistake and missed replacing all .* with [^,]* Once replacing all correctly, there is no issue now working as expected. Thanks for your attention and sorry for your time

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am not able to comment since my reputation is lower than 50. :(

Will the following regex work for you?

```
^([A-Za-z0-9\s\.]+\,){37}[A-Za-z0-9\s\.]+$
```

Comment: There are only 37 fields, you are matching 38.

Comment: He mentioned he need to validate 38 fields

Comment: then it unmatched the regex and should return false. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'm more concerned about per field validation. e.g. if 5th field is a word where I expect a number, I want it to fail. Also for non numeric parts, empty string is acceptable

Comment: in 2), your test string has 36 comma and your regex has 37 comma. And the performance is bad with a greedy quantifier when the regex fails to match the string. It's because regex engine has backtrack for greedy quantifier and it doesn't give up when it unmatched and goes back to check as many characters as needed.
[link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)